# why everytime we need to copy driver to project while working on netbeans database(JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, netbeans-8

Why every time we need to copy driver into our every  project while working on JDBC net beans. Is it always necessary. Why cant we just install it one time and use it with all our projects like we install drivers in our OS. I am learning how to work on JDBC and really annoyed to copy driver to every new project.

Comment: The reason is that you need to explicitly specify the dependencies of a project (and really, you don't need to copy it into your project, referencing the driver in a fixed location is sufficient). The usual solution is to use maven or gradle to declare the dependencies, and they'll be added automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to copy the JDBC driver to every project.

You can define the JDBC driver as a global library using Tools -> Library, e.g.:

[image]

Then in the properties of your project, select that library:

[image]

[image]